# HTML, javascript and jQuery - Beginner

Tags: jquery, html

I just started learning HTML, javascript and jQuery, but I can't link these three together. 
So far what I did is:
HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="alert-btn">Click me for alert</button>
</body>
```

javascript file:

```
$(".alert-btn").click(function(){
    alert("Hey there!");
});
```

So as you can see, I tried to put the links in the head part of html file, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to add?

Comment: is the javascript in your test.js file?

Comment: If you want to interact with the HTML (in your case by assigning a click handler), you should wait until the HTML is fully loaded. You can do this by wrapping all your JS code  in `$( document ).ready(...) ` see: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Maybe your path to javascript file is not correct. Look here, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/ovc6p0kq/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code:

```
$(".alert-btn").click(function(){
    alert("Hey there!");
});
```

is in the file `test.js` you should load this file after the DOM elements are loaded:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="alert-btn">Click me for alert</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely use the `$( document ).ready(...)  up in the header.